# Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with a specific command that I am using in a new game that I am creating inside of Minecraft. The command I have so far is:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{"text":"
[MF2]","color":"gold","clickEvent":
{"action":"run_command","value":"tellraw @a ["",{"text":"[MF2] 
","color":"gold"},{"selector":"@p","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":" is now an
admin of the server!","color":"white"}]"}}",Text3:"{"text":"Click to join
Admin","color":"dark_aqua","clickEvent":
{"action":"run_command","value":"scoreboard teams join admin @p"}}"},display:
{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

If I take out the `/tellraw` command, the command works fine, but I need the inner command to announce to the game that a new admin has joined.

With `/tellraw` inside, the error message reads:

> Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token `t` at:
>
> ```
> text":"[MF2]","color":"gold","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"tellraw
>   @a [""{"text":"[MF2] ","color":"gold"},
>   {"selector":"@p","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":" is now an admin 
>   of the server!","color":"white"}]"}}",Text3:"{"text":"Click to join
>   Admin","color":"dark_aqua","clickEvent":
>   {"action":"run_command","value":"scoreboard teams join admin @p"}}"
> ```

If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

---

Related:

- [Escaping inside of an already-escaped string](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290392/131559)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this particular part, which is causing the first error:

```
Text1:"{"text
```

1. Minecraft reads `Text:`, and  is expecting a string (surrounded with quotation marks) to follow
2. Minecraft reads `"`, so starts reading the string to go with Text1 (the key)
3. Minecraft reads `{` as the string
4. Minecraft reads `"`, so stops reading the string, and is now expecting a comma to start the next key-value pair, e.g: `Text1:"Hello",Text2:"World"`
5. Minecraft finds `t` instead, so throws the unexpected token error

To fix this, you need to escape (put a backslash before) quotation marks that are part of the JSON. `\"` tells Minecraft to read `"` just as another character in the string, rather than stopping reading the string, as the `"` is part of the JSON rather than the top-level NBTData.

Even more confusing is when you have a tellraw command, requiring JSON, within the sign's text JSON. You now need to escape the backslash itself (`\\`) before the quotation mark (`\"`) so that it's not read as NBTData, nor as the sign's text JSON, but as part of a string within the sign's text JSON.

Fully fixed command:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"[MF2]\",\"color\":\"gold\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tellraw @a [{\\\"text\\\":\\\"[MF2] \\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"gold\\\"},{\\\"selector\\\":\\\"@p\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"dark_aqua\\\"},{\\\"text\\\":\\\" is now an admin of the server!\\\",\\\"color\\\":\\\"white\\\"}]\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"Click to join Admin\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"scoreboard teams join admin @p\"}}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

In the future, use a generator, or use a `trigger`/`scoreboard` command to set off the `tellraw` command, as this can get pretty confusing and annoying to find errors in.

Answer (score 2):

*An updated solution that adds on to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246091/250180) other solution.*

In 1.14 and above, you can reduce the need for escape characters by surrounding your whole string with single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. This means that you can freely include `"`s in your string without escaping them with `\`s. However, this means that you will need to escape every `'` in your string.

Example:

```
/give @s dirt{display:{Name:'[{"text":"Hello, World!"}]'}}
```

Note that single and double quoted strings with the same text are considered equivalent. However, Minecraft now uses single-quoted strings for all strings containing JSON text components. This is evident because using `/data get` always shows JSON text components as single-quoted strings, no matter which format was used to type them out.

Comment: Nice, this method also works for specifying block states within a `setblock` command which is run from a server-side script using the `dimension.runCommandAsync` function.