# JSON Errors in Custom Signs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with a command that I am trying to make in a game inside of minecraft. It is a custom generated sign (using a sign generator) that allows players to upgrade their weapons (and armor).

The command is the following:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins=24] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @p [\\"\\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"You do not have enough wins to upgrade your sword.\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Upgrade Sword\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @p [\\"\\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"Sword upgraded!\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"$25\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p sword 1\"}}",Text4:"{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players remove @p wins 25\"}}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

The first line of the sign is empty, and the click-event runs an execute command that tells the player that they do not have enough wins to upgrade using a tellraw statement.

The second line of the sign says "Upgrade Sword", and the click-event runs an execute command that tells the player that they have enough wins and their sword has been upgraded using a tellraw statement.

The third line of the sign says "$25" (which is the amount of wins to upgrade), and the click-event runs an execute command that increments the "sword" scoreboard for the player by 1.

The fourth line of the sign is empty, and the click-event runs an execute command that subtracts 25 wins from the player using the "wins" scoreboard.

---

My error is displayed as shown:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token '\' at: \\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"You do not have enough wins to upgrade your sword.\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Upgrade Sword\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @p [\\"\\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"Sword upgraded!\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"$25\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p sword 1\"}}",Text4:"{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players remove @p wins 25\"}}"
```

I have a similar command creating a custom sign again and the problem seems to be the tellraw commands. [You can find my other question here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/need-help-with-a-specific-command)

I have tried using the answer from my other question to fix this command but I have just gotten completely lost. If anyone could help or explain to me how to use this properly (because I will also need to do this for other items), that would be fantastic.

Comment: If you were using a 1.9 generator with Minecraft 1.8 that could have been your problem.  1.8 can work with 1.9, but 1.9 can't work with 1.8.

Comment: @Jason_ That is incorrect. In 1.9, JSON must be strict. In 1.8, JSON *can* be strict. If you have lenient JSON from 1.8, it won't work in 1.9 because in 1.9 it must be strict. But 1.9 JSON will work perfectly in 1.8.

Comment: @Skylinerw, woops, sorry guess I didn't do my homework properly. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was smart before writing this huh... I only used one generator to try and make the command. As soon as I posted this I was like "hey lets try another one" and it worked. This is the working command:

> /blockdata ~ ~1 ~ {Text1:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins=24] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @p [\\"\\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"You do not have enough wins to upgrade your sword.\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"},\"text\":\"\"}]",Text2:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @p [\\"\\",{\\"text\\":\\"[MF2] \\",\\"color\\":\\"gold\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"[SHOP] \\",\\"color\\":\\"yellow\\"},{\\"text\\":\\"Sword upgraded!\\",\\"color\\":\\"none\\"}]\"},\"text\":\"Upgrade Sword\"}]",Text3:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @p sword 1\"},\"text\":\"25 Wins\",\"color\":\"green\"}]",Text4:"[{\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/execute @p[score_wins_min=25] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players remove @p wins 25\"},\"text\":\"\"}]"}

Well, I guess that solves that.

//Edit: The link to the generator I used is by MCtoolBox, and you can go straight to the sign generator by [clicking here](http://mctoolbox.me/sign/).