# Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this Minecraft /give command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a sign that you can right click and it will clear cacti from your inventory, then give you 18 cookies named "$100 Cookie" with the lore "$100". But when I put it in a command block and power it, the command block says this:

> [04:23:51] Data tag parsing failed: Unexpected token `$` at: `$100 Cookie\\",Lore:[$100]}}\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"iIiIiIi\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"strikethrough\":true,\"obfuscated\":true}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true}"`

The command I'm using is:

```
give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"clear @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] cactus 0 2304\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"2304 Cacti\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"give @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] minecraft:cookie 18 0 {display:{Name:\"$100 Cookie\",Lore:[$100]}}\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"iIiIiIi\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"strikethrough\":true,\"obfuscated\":true}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

What's wrong with this command? I've tried backslashes and stuff. Can you please try to fix the command and test out your potential fix in-game? Thank you!

You'll have to change the `[name=rainbowlack,r=3]` parts to whatever your username is (example: `[name=playerplayer123,r=3]`).

---

Related: [Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246064/131244)

Comment: The current duplicate target on this question only covers the first level of escaping. This question is about the second level of escaping, and a question on the first level of escaping will not help them to solve this problem. I'm voting to reopen this question for that reason. If you disagree, please reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add more escape characters to deeper-nested quotation marks. You open the `Text1` tag with a `"`, thus the very next `"` character closes it. You open the `value` tag for the click event with `\"`, meaning the next `\"` you use will close it, which occurs in your nested `/give` command's NBT data (specifically just after the `Name` tag). That it what's causing your issue.

The formula to determine the number of backslashes required is: `2n+1`, where `n` is the number of current backslashes. For the nested NBT data, you need 3 backslashes per quotation mark (`\\\"`).

Fixed command:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"clear @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] cactus 0 2304\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"2304 Cacti\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"give @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] minecraft:cookie 18 0 {display:{Name:\\\"$100 Cookie\\\",Lore:[$100]}}\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"iIiIiIi\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"strikethrough\":true,\"obfuscated\":true}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place backslashes in front of the `$` symbols. If the rest of the command is correct, this should work:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"clear @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] cactus 0 2304\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"2304 Cacti\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"give @p[name=rainbowlack,r=3] minecraft:cookie 18 0 {display:{Name:\"\$100 Cookie\",Lore:[\$100]}}\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"iIiIiIi\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"strikethrough\":true,\"obfuscated\":true}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

Also, including the username shouldn't be necessary as far as I can tell. Why not:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"clear @p cactus 0 2304\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"2304 Cacti\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"give @p minecraft:cookie 18 0 {display:{Name:\"\$100 Cookie\",Lore:[\$100]}}\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"iIiIiIi\",\"color\":\"light_purple\",\"strikethrough\":true,\"obfuscated\":true}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"[Sell]\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\",\"bold\":true}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```

Comment: The sign is visible, but the 2nd row says {"text":"2304 and doesn't give me the cookies!

Comment: What is the desired output of the 2nd line?

Comment: I want it to say "2304 Cacti" in red and for it to give me 18 cookies with the name "$100 Cookie" and lore "$100"

Comment: Dollar signs do not require escaping and will not fix the issue.

Comment: Then why does @rainbowlack receive this error, which is fixed (or at least the command block accepts it) when adding escape characters? The evidence doesn't support your statement. I feel sad that people downvote me for providing a valid answer (regarldess of the fact that a 2nd problem appeared when this was fixed).

Comment: See my answer as to what the issue is. The error message received in the OP is referring to broken NBT input; for example, when specifying `tag1:"data"notoken`. The "notoken" part is missing a separator (comma), thus the error is going to be "unexpected token 'n'. That does **not** mean you escape the "n". The issue here is the data was closed early due to the lack of necessary escape characters for quotation marks, throwing the parser off track. The error message in this case is not directly helpful in solving the issue. No new issue arose; it'll never work without proper quote escaping.