# How to embed quoted commands in a sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to run a title command when a player right clicks a sign. Here is my command for spawning the sign (generated here):

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {
    BlockEntityTag: {
        Text1: "{\"text\":\"---------------\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tp @s 0 66 13\"}}",
        Text2: "{\"text\":\"Right click once\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"playsound entity.player.levelup master @s ~ ~ ~ 10 1\"}}",
        Text3: "{\"text\":\"accepted!\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/title @s title {\\"text\\":\\"Welcome to the Server!\\", \\"bold\\":true, \\"italic\\":false, \\"color\\":\\"green\\"}\"}}",
        Text4: "{\"text\":\"---------------\"}"
    },
    display: {
        Name: "Custom Sign"
    }
}
```

However I get an error here:

```
{\\"t <---
```

I assume because of the double escape characters or nested quotes, but I tried single quotes and tried single escape characters to no avail. How would I run this command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-are-my-quotation-marks-causing-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command)

Comment: @pppery I'm not seeing what you're seeing. Which line and column do you see said problem?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I flagged this not because of my own reading of the command, but because the accepted answer is "you need to add more backslashes to your quotes", which is covered in that question.

Comment: @pppery That question only covers the first level of escaping characters. This question is about the second level of escaping.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this Minecraft /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290392/185203), which is unambiguously about the second level of escaping, was closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @pppery Then I'm going to have to disagree with that closure also. I would reopen that one and then close this one as a duplicate of the second post you've just mentioned. If not, then edit the duplicate target of that one to point to this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this Minecraft /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290392/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-minecraft-give-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  You saw that the title command required double escapement of the special characters.  In your case, you tried `\\"`.  A quote which is single escaped is `\"`.  To double escape it, you have to escape both characters which gives `\\\"`

Here is a working command with the changes:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"---------------\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tp @s 0 66 13\"}}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Right click once\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"playsound entity.player.levelup master @s ~ ~ ~ 10 1\"}}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"accepted!\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/title @s title {\\\"text\\\":\\\"Welcome to the Server!\\\", \\\"bold\\\":true, \\\"italic\\\":false, \\\"color\\\":\\\"green\\\"}\"}}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"---------------\"}"},display:{Name:"Custom Sign"}}
```