# how do i make a sign spawn in a command block with code inside already

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i am making a map and i want to make a feature where you click on a sign and command blocks spawn around you and you see the map build it self.
but when ever i use the format:

```
/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Click to","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:repeating_command_block{Command:\\"command here\\"}"}}',Text2:'{"text":"generate"}',Text3:'{"text":"the map"}'},display:{Name:'{"text":"Map gen"}'}}
```

it shows me an error and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: also worth mentioning that to make the command blocks paste the map i have uploaded various scematic to the mc server

it works when i use only the command block but when i try to click the sign it spawns the command block but with out the command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use quotes in an extremely nested command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384883/how-do-i-use-quotes-in-an-extremely-nested-command)