# How to /setblock a sign that, when clicked, it gives a stick with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to use the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ oak_sign{Text2:"[{\"text\":\"CLICK TO DIE\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/give GodOfTheFlame stick{display:{Name:"\"SuperStick\""}}\"}}]",}
```

but whenever I try it it doesn't work. GodOfTheFlame is my username, by the way.
However, when I try the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ oak_sign{Text2:"[{\"text\":\"CLICK TO DIE\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"kill @p\"}}]",}
```

it works beutifully.

If someone can help me, please do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this Minecraft /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290392/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-minecraft-give-command) (and for what it's worth I find this to be clear enough)