# Having ""strings in ""strings in a "nested" command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I am having a problem with a nested command, I made a "one command" creator a while ago and I am trying to make it work again, so what it does is: spawn a lot of minecart command blocks on an activator rail and this executes them, then I want the command block minecarts to execute the commands that set block the real working command blocks because there are no repeating command block minecarts. But the problem that I am having is that the command in the minecarts needs to have a nested command in it for the command block that it set blocks, which looks like this:

```
Passengers:[{id:command_block_minecart,Motion:[0.0,.8,0.0],Command:"/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:repeating_command_block{Command: ["execute as @e[tag=s] at @s run summon tnt ~ ~ ~"]}"
```

But this approach puts two ""strings into each other so like this: command: "command:""" and this doesn't work. Does someone know how I can use this character: `"` in a string in Minecraft?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the inner " with `\ `?

Comment: Thanks, this worked! (I feel very dumb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this Minecraft /give command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290392/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-minecraft-give-command)

Comment: I think this should be opened for review because it is a different more specific question than the reason for closing.

Comment: @BlueRobin Unfortunately this is still a duplicate, if not of the current duplicate link, then of [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246064/250180) which covers the first level of escaping. Make sure you have searched thoroughly for other potential duplicates before submitting for review.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ExpertCoder14 I understand now.