# How would I summon a command block minecart which in it has a command to setblock another command block and in that have a command in it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is what I have so far:

```
/summon command_block_minecart ~ ~ ~ {Command:"setblock ~ ~ ~5 command_block[facing=south]{Command:"setblock ~3 ~ ~ stone"}"}
```

It's supposed to summon a command block minecart at my feet, setblock a command block 5 blocks away, and that (powered by some already existing redstone source) will place stone 3 blocks away. I can't seem to get it to work it's saying I can't add quotation marks or curly brackets. It would be very helpful if someone explains the correct way to do something like this or give me the command

Comment: There's nothing in there that targets you.  It looks like you need an execute command.

Comment: @MBraedley Nothing in there needs to target you, since the player is typing the command, so it targeted by default. The actual problem is ...

Comment: ... already covered by [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command), making this question a duplicate.