# Trying to make a sign give me diamonds if i press it with 64 stone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use this command to give me the sign with the right "click" command:

```
/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"ex\", \"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\", \"value\":\"execute as @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone", Count:64b}}] run give @p minecraft:diamond\"}}"}}
```

But Minecraft comes with a error msg that says `"Expected '}' at position 175: ...Item:id"<--[HERE]"`. What is the problem here?

If I use this it runs fine:

```
execute as @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone", Count:64b}}] run say hi
```

Comment: Here’s something that can help you out! [Why am I getting an 'unexpected token' error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command) This is the problem that you’ll have to search for and correct throughout the command.