# How to set a command block to set a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to setblock a command block to setblock a command block with a command inside.

For example:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block{Command:"say hi"}
```

works, but:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block{Command:"setblock ~ ~1 ~ command_block{Command:"say hi"}"}
```

does not work (it says its missing a bracket). Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong link. Possible duplicate of [Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246064/185203)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have quotation marks inside quotation marks you need to use a backslash before the quotation marks (\"):

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block{Command:"setblock ~ ~1 ~ command_block{Command:\"say hi\"}"}
```

This is not just in Minecraft commands, it is also a feature of many programming languages.

It can get quite confusing:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block{Command:"setblock ~ ~1 ~ command_block{Command:\"setblock ~ ~1 ~ command_block{Command:\\\"say hi\\\"}\"}"}
```