# Getting a command block with command inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have gotten commands into command blocks before with the /setblock. For whatever reason, this does not want to work even though this is the command.

/setblock -477 6 1146 minecraft:command_block{Command:"/summon falling_block ~ ~2 ~2 {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:command_block"},Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:"say hi",auto:1b},Time:1}"}

it gives me an error any suggestions

Comment: This other question has the exact same error, so I'm marking this one as a duplicate. Although it doesn't have the exact same command, please use those inferring skills of yours to apply the solution to your own command. [Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-are-my-quotation-marks-causing-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command)

Comment: Can't you spawn the block, and *then* deploy it's command? Would save a lot of trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Acording To gamepedia :

```
summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:redstone_block},Passengers:[ {id:armor_stand,Health:0,Passengers:[ {id:falling_block,Time:1,BlockState:{Name:activator_rail},Passengers:[ {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'gamerule commandBlockOutput false'}, {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'data merge block ~ ~-2 ~ {auto:0}'}, {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'PUT FIRST COMMAND HERE'}, {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'PUT SECOND COMMAND HERE'}, {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'setblock ~ ~1 ~ command_block{auto:1,Command:"fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~-2 ~ air"}'}, {id:command_block_minecart,Command:'kill @e[type=command_block_minecart,distance=..1]'}]}]}]}
```

But it is for multiple commands.

Comment: You don't actually need falling blocks to get this done. Falling blocks are an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 please dont Down Vote. Plsplspls

Comment: I'd be very happy to change my vote to an upvote once you can change this answer to something acceptable. But at this current state I would not recommend this answer to someone else. The downvote is there to indicate people should not do this.

Comment: I'm not angry at you, but I'd really like to see an improvement to the content in this answer. I believe in you, I think you can do it!