# Command works, but not when placed in another command black

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm putting together a command block that places a command block. The command works on it's own, but when I place it in the command block it doesn't.

The command that's being placed is a simple armor stand placing a custom player head in the head slot:

`/summon armor_stand ~ ~3 ~ {NoGravity:1,Invisible:1,Small:1,Tags:[CircularGlobe],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-354915383,-611561958,-1478611804,1281502000],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZmMxZTczMDIzMzUyY2JjNzdiODk2ZmU3ZWEyNDJiNDMxNDNlMDEzYmVjNWJmMzE0ZDQxZTVmMjY1NDhmYjJkMiJ9fX0="}]}}}}]}`

The next command should be simple too, but for some reason it does not work:

`setblock ~ ~2 ~ command_block[facing=up,]{Command:"/summon armor_stand ~ ~3 ~ {NoGravity:1,Invisible:1,Small:1,Tags:[CircularGlobe],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-354915383,-611561958,-1478611804,1281502000],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZmMxZTczMDIzMzUyY2JjNzdiODk2ZmU3ZWEyNDJiNDMxNDNlMDEzYmVjNWJmMzE0ZDQxZTVmMjY1NDhmYjJkMiJ9fX0="}]}}}}]}",auto:1b}`

I thought I did everything right; am I just missing a bracket somewhere or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my quotation marks causing an “unexpected token” error with this command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246064/why-are-my-quotation-marks-causing-an-unexpected-token-error-with-this-command)

Comment: @pppery Why do you think that's a duplicate?

Comment: @Joachim I _think_ the first `"` after `Command:` in the second code block does not have a proper closing quote from what I can tell.

Comment: The actual problem is that the inner quotes within the commands need backslashes, as is explained by the duplicate.